# How to calculating groupwise mean

Tags: data

I have a huge panel data with more than 2.5 million observations and more than 15000 groups. I want to calculate group-wise mean and I also need Id variable in my result.  This is what I have done.

```
dat = {{2, .1, .2}, {2, .2, .4}, {2, .3, .6}, {2, .4, .8}, {5, 1, 
    2}, {5, 2, 4}, {7, 20, 10}, {7, 40, 20}, {7, 60, 30}, {7, 80, 
    40}, {7, 100, 50}, {10, 30, 50}};

results =  Table[N[Mean[Select[dat, #[[1]] == i &]]], {i, {2, 5, 7, 10}}];
```

But it is taking too long time. How can we make it quicker.
Also, I want to calculate group-wise max value of second column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you want `Mean /@ GatherBy[dat, First]` OR  `Mean /@ GroupBy[dat, First]` ?

Comment: @RunnyKine. I am so stupid. Its that simple. It works and pretty fact. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first case, the following should work:

```
Mean /@ GatherBy[dat, First]
```

OR

```
Mean /@ GroupBy[dat, First]
```

The second case gives an association with index as `Keys`

For the maximum by second value, try:

```
MaximalBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ GatherBy[dat, First]
```

OR

```
MaximalBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ GroupBy[dat, First]
```

Comment: SplitBy[dat, First] works also.

Comment: @Algohi, that will only work if common terms are next to each other.

Comment: yes of course if they are next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

```
Values @ GroupBy[dat, First, Mean]
```

> {{2, 0.25, 0.5}, {5, 3/2, 3}, {7, 60, 30}, {10, 30, 50}}

```
Values @ Merge[Mean][# -> {##} & @@@ dat]
```

> {{2, 0.25, 0.5}, {5, 3/2, 3}, {7, 60, 30}, {10, 30, 50}}

Comment: Thank you kglr. This was my question toward the beginning of my journey. I started to get it now.

Comment: @ramesh, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said your dataset had 2.5 million entries and 15000 groups, you might try using my [`GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158637/45431) function to gain a small improvement in speed when compared to the other answers. Here is the definition of `GatherByList`:

```
GatherByList[list_, representatives_] := Module[{func},
    func /: Map[func, _] := representatives;
    GatherBy[list, func]
]
```

And here is a dataset with 2.5 million entries and ~15000 groups:

```
data = RandomInteger[15000, {2500000, 3}];
```

Here's a comparison with the other answers for obtaining the [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean):

```
r1 = Values @ GroupBy[data, First, Mean]; //AbsoluteTiming (* kglr *)
r2 = Mean /@ GatherBy[data, First]; //AbsoluteTiming (* Runnykine *)
r3 = Mean /@ GatherByList[data, data[[All, 1]]]; //AbsoluteTiming (* Carl *)

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.355567, Null}
>
> {0.311108, Null}
>
> {0.278283, Null}
>
> True

And a comparison with @Runnykine's answer for obtaining the element with the group-wise max of the second column:

```
r1 = Last @ MaximalBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ GatherBy[data, First]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Module[{r = GatherByList[data, data[[All, 1]]]},
    #[[First @ Ordering[#[[All, 2]], -1]]]& /@ r
]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {1.525, Null}
>
> {0.275054, Null}
>
> True

Comment: @ Carl, thank you for answer.