# While partitioning the elements in a list using GatherBy, can I correspondingly partition the elements of an unrelated list?

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

If we have a list like the following:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

And we use `GatherBy` to subpartition is according to a test function

```
GatherBy[list1, Mod[#, 3] &]
```

We have as an output for this example `{{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}}`.  See Artes' answer to my previous question: [Subpartitioning elements of a list based on some h[ri] == h[rj] test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67463/subpartitioning-elements-of-a-list-based-on-some-hri-hrj-test)

However, can we subpartition an unrelated list of the same length as `list1`, some `list2` with arbitrary elements, in the same manner as `list1` is subpartitioned via `GatherBy`?

For example, let's write some nonsense in list format:

```
list2 = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", "complained", "I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"};
```

If we sort this list via the `GatherBy` output of the first list, we would have:

```
list2bylist1 = {{"It", "the", "man", "shall"}, {"is", "morning", "complained", "consider"}, {"only", "the", "I", "nothing"}};
```

Is there a way to do this simply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}; 
list2 = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", "complained", "I", "shall", 
         "consider", "nothing"}; 
GatherBy[Transpose[{list1, list2}], Mod[#[[1]], 3] &][[All, All, 2]]

(* {{"It", "the", "man", "shall"}, {"is", "morning", "complained",  "consider"}, 
    {"only", "the", "I", "nothing"}} *)
```

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds.

Comment: @Szabolcs I made an answering bot using the new v10 natural lang features :)

Comment: @Szabolcs If I wish the test to be only that the elements at the indices are equal in list1 (without applying Mod 3), may I write: GatherBy[Transpose[{list1, list2}], #[[1]] &][[All, All, 2]]?

Comment: @SShepard Yes, That's it

Comment: @belisarius Thank you.

Comment: @belisarius Actually, may I ask why is it is #[[1]] instead of just #?

Comment: @SShepard Because you're grouping by the first element of each element of `Transpose[{list1, list2}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Any reason you would fall back to a dectorate method rather than your own method, posted by kguler?

Answer (score 12):

Here is another approach. The basic idea is that [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy) creates a list of representatives corresponding to the input, then partitions the input based on those representatives. We can see this in action with [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace). Here is an example:

```
func[x_] := Mod[x, 3]
Trace[GatherBy[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, func], TraceInternal->True]
```

> {GatherBy[{1,2,3,4,5},func],{func/@{1,2,3,4,5},{func[1],func[2],func[3],func[4],func[5]},{func[1],Mod[1,3],1},{func[2],Mod[2,3],2},{func[3],Mod[3,3],0},{func[4],Mod[4,3],1},{func[5],Mod[5,3],2},{1,2,0,1,2}},{{1,4},{2,5},{3}}}

Notice how [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy) internally computes `func /@ {1,2,3,4,5}` to create the list of representatives `{1, 2, 0, 1, 2}`. This list of representatives is then used to partition the input. So, to answer your question, we can override the [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map) so that it uses an alternate list of representatives. Here is a function that does this:

```
GatherByList[list_, representatives_] := Module[{func},
    func /: Map[func, _] := representatives;
    GatherBy[list, func]
]
```

For your example:

```
GatherByList[list2, Mod[list1, 3]]
```

> {{"It", "the", "man", "shall"}, {"is", "morning", "complained", 
>     "consider"}, {"only", "the", "I", "nothing"}}

Let's compare timings with the accepted answer:

```
list1 = Range[10^6];
list2 = RandomReal[1, 10^6];

r1 = GatherByList[list2, Mod[list1, 3]]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = GatherBy[Transpose[{list1, list2}], Mod[#[[1]], 3] &][[All, All, 2]]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.013, Null}
>
> {1.36, Null}
>
> True

So, `GatherByList` is 2 orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Will `func` stay in scope or not? It looks like it'll incur a memory leak as it has a reference to `Map`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Did you check? I expect it will be garbage collected, and it does seem to be. Typically variables leave scope when they are included in the output, which is not the case here.

Comment: Nah, but when I used `Module` variables to attempt to construct a bound method it blew up in my face. On the other hand, I was returning one of those methods so the reference to some outer-scope function was kept.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
idx = GatherBy[list1, Mod[#, 3] &]

list2 = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", "complained", 
      "I", "shall",   "consider", "nothing"};

Part[list2, #] & /@ idx
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This only works because `list1` is Range[12].  You need a variation if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Using a variant of [Szabolcs's `positionDuplicates`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates/21344#21344):

```
shapeLikeF1[l1_List, l2_List, tstF_] :=
    Extract[l1, List /@ GatherBy[Range @ Length @ l2, tstF @ l2[[#]] &]]

shapeLikeF2[l1_List, l2_List, tstF_] :=
    l1[[#]] & /@ GatherBy[Range @ Length @ l2, tstF @ l2[[#]] &]
```

Examples:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
list2 = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", "complained", 
          "I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"};

shapeLikeF1[list2, list1, Mod[#, 3] &]

(* {{"It","the","man","shall"},{"is","morning","complained", "consider"},
{"only","the","I","nothing"}} *)

shapeLikeF1[list1, list2, StringLength]

(* {{1,2},{3},{4,6,7},{5,12},{8},{9},{10},{11}} *)
```

`shapeLikeF2` produces the same output.

Comment: This uses [Szabolcs's method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-to-efficiently-find-positions-of-duplicates/21344#21344) and it is probably the fastest non-compiled way.  (+1)  Would you mind if I rewrite these using standard pattern definitions rather than `With`?  I find the existing code unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: @MrWizard, please go ahead..

Comment: Okay.  I shall take the liberty of eliminating the duplicate examples as well; it should be sufficient to state that they produce the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Just for something different:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
list2 = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", 
   "complained", "I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"};
Join @@ Last@
  Reap[MapThread[Sow[#2, Mod[#1, 3]] &, {list1, list2}], _, List@#2 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

b = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", "complained", "I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"};

c = GatherBy[a, Mod[#, 3] &]
```

{{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}}

Using `TakeList` (new in 11.2):

```
TakeList[b, Length /@ c]
```

{{"It", "is", "only", "the"}, {"morning", "the", "man",
"complained"}, {"I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"}}

Also:

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[c, b]
```

{{"It", "is", "only", "the"}, {"morning", "the", "man",
"complained"}, {"I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` and `Thread`:

```
la = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

lb = {"It", "is", "only", "the", "morning", "the", "man", 
      "complained", "I", "shall", "consider", "nothing"};

Values[GroupBy[Thread[la -> lb], Mod[#[[1]], 3] &]][[All, All, 2]]

(*{{"It", "the", "man", "shall"},
   {"is", "morning", "complained", "consider"},
   {"only", "the", "I", "nothing"}}*)
```