# Obtain all the (multinomial) subsets

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set, lets say: `set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I want to get all the possible subsets with 1, 2, and 2 elements.

What I did was to generate all possible permutations (5!) of set and use `TakeList`:

```
allofthem = TakeList[#, {2, 2, 1}] & /@ Permutations[set]
```

Afterwards, I had to order them (at level 2) and use `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[
  Table[Map[Sort, allofthem[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[allofthem]}]]
```

I would like to do this in a simpler way, perhaps avoiding the use of `Table`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get `TakeList`? AFAIK that is not a built-in Mathematica function.

Comment: Have you seen `Subsets[]` already?

Comment: @m_goldberg `TakeList` was introduced in MMA 11.2

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci. Thanks. I'm still using 11.1

Comment: `Tuples[Range[5], 1]` and `Tuples[Range[5],2]`?

Comment: it didn't work Subsets or Tuples :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this other way of doing it:

```
ReplaceAll[#, 0 -> Nothing] & /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort /@ ArrayReshape[#, {3, 2}] & /@ Permutations[Range[5]]]
```

Although it is restriceted to subsets of 2,2, and 1 elements.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**
As noted in the comments, the dummy set can be based on numbers too. The result would still be the same.

```
setDummy[sub_] := ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[{Range[Length[sub]], sub}] // Flatten
setDummy[{2,2,1}]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}

---

One way would be to use a dummy set to represent required permutations such as `{x, x, y, y, z}`. Subsequently, obtain permutations of it and then arrange `set` accordingly to achieve the desired result.

```
set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
setDummy = {x, x, y, y, z};
res = Keys @ GatherBy[#, Last] & /@ (Thread[set -> #] & /@ Permutations[setDummy])
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 
>      5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 
>      3}, {5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 
>      5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 
>      5}}, {{1, 5}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 
>      3}, {4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 
>      5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 
>      4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 
>      5}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4, 
>      5}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 
>      5}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 
>      5}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}

```
set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
allofthem = Internal`PartitionRagged[#, {2, 2, 1}] & /@ Permutations[set];
res1 = DeleteDuplicates[Table[Map[Sort, allofthem[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[allofthem]}]];
Sort[(Sort /@ res)] == Sort[Sort /@ res1]
```

> True

Comment: very nice! thanks! although it would be necessary to generate the dummy set for different partitions.

Comment: Here I have used a symbolic set, you can indeed generate a number based set for different partitions i.e., `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}`. The code would work exactly as previous.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a repackaging of @Anjan's nice answer. I will make use of  my function [`GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158637/45431):

```
GatherByList[list_, representatives_] := Module[{func},
    func /: Map[func,_] := representatives;
    GatherBy[list,func]
]
```

Then, I will define a function to produce a result for an input partition:

```
multiSet[partition_] := With[
    {
    perms = Permutations[Flatten @ Map[ConstantArray[Unique[], #]&] @ partition],
    elems = Range @ Total[partition]
    },

    GatherByList[elems, #]& /@ perms
]
```

Example:

```
multiSet[{2, 2, 1}]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 
>      3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5}}, {{1, 
>      5}, {2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 
>      3}, {2}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 
>      4}, {2, 3}, {5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 
>      3}, {2, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3}}, {{1, 
>      2}, {3, 4}, {5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 
>      5}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 
>      3}, {4, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 
>      5}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}

Comment: Very Nice Carl!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

1) define a grouping vector:

```
grp = {1, 2, 2}
```

2) Define the indexes to use in `Take`  (could this be improved by using `Mod`?)

```
grp2 = Union /@ 
  Transpose[List[Accumulate[grp] - grp + 1, Accumulate[grp]]]
```

or better:

```
grp2=Range[Accumulate[grp] - grp + 1, Accumulate[grp]]
```

3) Define a function with `Take` and `grp2`

```
take[x__] := Take[x, #] & /@ grp2
```

4) Find all the (Multinomial) subsets grouped according to grp

```
psubsets = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ take[#] & /@ Permutations[Range[5]]];
```